# jquery ui datepicker take value 1970 if input field is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

i am using jquery ui date picker for take fromDate and toDate

Following is the code of from date

```
 <input name="from_date" id="from_date" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text"/>  

   $("#from_date").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'M dd, yy',
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            defaultDate: null
        });
```

now i use the form to take the value in POST varible using PHP
   If the fromDate field is blank then it take value '**1970-01-01**' i want it blank

Comment: Can you include the PHP script where you get the variable ? are you casting to another type in PHP ?

Comment: Following is the my PHP code   `$sdate = showDate($_POST['from_date'],'Y-m-d');`

Comment: and the showDate() function ?

Comment: my guess is that when using `showDate` or other `date` functions in PHP if the input is `empty` of `null` then the date that is created is epoch (ie 1970-01-01)

Comment: It is my function to return blank value if POST date is null `function showDate($date,$format='m-d-y, h:i a') 
{
 if(is_null($date))
  return ' ';
 return date($format,strtotime($date));
}`

Comment: $date wont be null ... its probably going to be '' = an empty string .... echo it / log it and see

Comment: Instead check if date is null why don't you check if post value is equal to '1970-01-01'?

Comment: @Matteo - that wont work if the user can select that date ....

Comment: @hRaval you can instance a javascript var with null value and overwrite it only on DatePicker [onSelect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) event. So if this var remains null, it means that user have selected nothing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your PHP function is use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead of null

```
function showDate($date,$format='m-d-y, h:i a') {
   if(empty($date)) return ' ';
   return date($format,strtotime($date)); 
}
```

Comment: it works thanks ManseUK, there is issue with my PHP function i set the condition on NULL value

Answer (score 2):

try to set `defaultDate: ''` or remove it at all

Answer (score 2):

As you can find in jquery ui documentation ([here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)), if you don't precise `defaultDate` option, default date is current date.

Comment: No its not -> defaultDate    Default:null

Comment: @ManseUK Read better... "Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank. Specify either an actual date via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), **or null for today**".

Comment: Apologies - null does in deed equal today ... anyhow that isnt the problem here - defaultDate is the date first selected when the date picker is opened ....