# jQuery Datepicker Input Box Set To 01-01-1970 When Empty

Tags: jquery, html

guys i have an issue with Datepicker in my input box, labelled "Order Date".
Here is my input field :
[image: my input field with labelled "Order Date"]

When my form is submitted with a blank date field, it automatically get sets to 01-01-1970.

Like this :
[image: After submitting the form with a blank field]

So, here what i want is when i submitted my form with a blank field it should be set to blank rather than 01-01-1970.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978787/jquery-ui-datepicker-take-value-1970-if-input-field-is-blank

Comment: try to set `defaultDate: ''` in datepicker options or remove it

Comment: nothing get done automatically, there must be some code which is setting this value.

Comment: I believe you are using php and somewhere using strtotime function. Please see the following explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984595/php-date-showing-1970-01-01-after-conversion

Comment: @Taimur Khan yes bro, you are right. i am using a strtotime function something like this : $_POST['bOrderDate']    = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $_POST['bOrderDate'] ) );

Comment: @TaimurKhan but i already replace the / with -

Comment: @TaimurKhan but i am converting the date for my datepicker format "d-m-Y" to "Y-m-d" after submission of my form

Comment: Are you taking care of blank or empty value? if there is empty value in order date field you will get 01-01-1970 from strtotime function

Comment: @TaimurKhan yes.inside that input box i checked it's value like this value="<?php echo ( isset( $_POST['bOrderDate'] ) && !empty( $_POST['bOrderDate'] ) ) ? date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_POST['bOrderDate'])) : ''; ?>"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78380/discussion-between-taimur-khan-and-vitally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change `!empty($_POST['bOrderDate'])` as follows 
`!empty(trim($_POST['bOrderDate']))` that will solve the issue.